# Can I change the "From" name and address without going into Mail.app's preferences?

Tags: macos, apple-mail, alias

Can I somehow add an editable "From" field to Mail.app, a bit like [Virtual Identity](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/594) for Thunderbird, just like I could [change](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22257) the "Reply To" address on the fly?

In Mail.app, one can set up multiple email addresses for a single account by [just entering](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA23485) a comma-seperated list like `arjan@example.com, arjan+superuser@example.com`. Next, when composing a message, Mail offers a dropdown to *select* a "From" address. And when replying<sup>†</sup>, it automatically selects the right address if it can find a match:

[image]

[image]

Nice, but I'd like to be able to *change* the "From" on the fly, without going into the Account Information.

Also, in previous versions of Mail one could even specify multiple Full Names for a single account:

> Email Address: Arjan <arjan@example.com>, Arjan on SU <arjan+superuser@example.com>

But nowadays, Mail only uses the setting of Full Name, and even ignores names in the Email Address field when no value for Full Name is set at all. Hence, it would be great if I could change the Full Name on the fly as well.

I had no luck finding [a plugin for Mail](http://www.hawkwings.net/plugins.htm) yet.

<sup><sup>†</sup> When using [sub-addressing aka address tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Address_tags), *anything* that is sent to `me+whatever@example.com` is simply delivered to `me@example.com`. I'd then like to reply with the same full address, rather than just `me@example.com` if Mail cannot find a match, without going into the Account Information first. I sometimes also want to compose a new message with a new sub-addressing-address.</sup>

Comment: followed some link in a Meta comment here.  arjan, i'm so sorry.  buy me a Mac and i'll help you figure it out.  :)

Comment: Sorry, the current incarnation of Mail.app definitely does not support what you want to do.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to have separate identities like this. If using Lion's Mail.app, open 
`~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Accounts.plist` in a property list editor (I used Xcode's built-in one). Be sure to close Mail first and make a backup of the plist file.

Under `MailAccounts` there are a few `Item` dictionaries, from 0 to 2 in my case. Expand the one that contains the `EmailAddresses` key (`Item 2` for me).

You need to create a new key called `EmailAliases` as a sibling of `EmailAddresses` (i.e. at the same level on the plist tree), if it doesn't already exist. (It probably won't since Mail.app doesn't have an interface to create these aliases AFAIK.) Make it a type **Array**.

For each "Some Name" <some@address.com> pair you want to use, you need to repeat the following three steps:

1. Create a new **Dictionary** item inside the `EmailAliases` array.
2. Create a key called **name** inside the dictionary, with a type of **String**, and set its value to the name you wish to use, e.g. **Some Name**.
3. Create a key called **alias** inside the dictionary, with a type of **String**, and set its value to the address you want to pair with the full name you just entered, e.g. **some@address.com**

Be careful to put all the items in the correct tree levels. The **name** and **alias** keys are siblings, the key names have to be lowercase, and their values must not have quotes around them.

Save the plist when you're done and restart Mail. The "From" dropdown in the new message window should now contain the name/address alias pairs you just created. If they don't, recheck the structure. I've confirmed this method to work in Mail.app for OS X 10.7.1.

(Just to be explicit: you **don't** need to edit the `EmailAddresses` array or the `FullUserName` key at all when using the above method.)

Comment: Tried this on Mavericks & works like a charm!

Comment: Works like a charm on Yosemite and Mail 8.2! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree with MacLemon -- I don't believe Mail.app is going to do what you want.

You can, however, run Thunderbird on the Mac, as you know it does what you want.

http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/

Drop a line to apple's product feedback, then tend to listen.

Comment: Too bad, Thunderbird's large email files in combination with Time Machine is a no go for me.

Comment: @Arjan: You can set Time Machine to ignore certain folders. Simply find where Thunderbird stores the mail files and add that to the ignored files in Time Machine prefs.

Comment: @Mr.Man, hence not backing up my messages? No thanks! Anyway, the question specifically asks about Mail.app (which has GREAT integration with Time Machine by the way).

Answer (score -1):

The best answer here is to go to the View menu, and choose "Reply-to Field".  This would allow you to change the visible reply to field....